# IMS LTI implementation with node js express

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, lti, ims

I have a web application running using javascript stack, Nodejs express as a server and I am using passport as well for the cookie session.
We need to implement IMS LTI so users of other educational platforms can access ours with out creating an account.
The documentations on their website are really complicated and not well explained.
I don't know where to start from. If someone has an experience with such a thing or have any idea where to start from. Please help me out

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this answer might help you get started: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56917467

It refers to a very recent NPM package: https://github.com/Cvmcosta/ltijs

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I am interested too , hope some knows how to do that